# Accepting payment on behalf of someone else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment

I have organizations who have users that pay to join.  I need to be able to accept payments on my rails app and send the money(minus a potential charge that goes to me) to the organization's bank account.

Currently I have only found services to accept payments(fee #1) and then separate services that distribute payments(fee #2).  I am looking for a service that is easy to implement and combines these steps; preferably wrapped up in a nice ruby gem.

Comment: ?ActiveMerchant + paypal?

Comment: That's 2 steps, correct? Accepting money with active merchant then distributing with paypal?

Comment: No, ActiveMerchant is your link to paypal... You use active merchant to accept and distribute payments using paypal as your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest Stripe, I've implemented it before, the documentation is very clean and the gems worked fine

How you could use it:

1. Organizations needs to create an account on stripe
2. You will implement in your platform a way to organizations login on stripe through your platform, when they do that they will create a permission to your platform to receive payment in their behalf
3. You can set a value you will receive for each transaction
4. Stripe will distribute the money automatically after each payment